# Why does tar list multiple entries for some files?

Tags: python, tar

In a folder with a single file (image.jpg) I run the following commands

```
$ ls -a
.         ..        image.jpg
$ tar cf target.tar image.jpg
```

Listing contents of the archive

```
$ tar tvf target.tar
-rwxrwxrwx  0 Oskar  staff     190  8 Feb 12:14 ./._image.jpg
-rwxrwxrwx  0 Oskar  staff  404968  8 Feb 12:14 image.jpg
```

Extracting archive

```
$ tar xzf target.tar
$ ls -a
.         ..        image.jpg  target.tar
```

Why does the list of files in the archive show two files?

I'm running this in OSX 10.11.5.

```
$ tar --version
bsdtar 2.8.3 - libarchive 2.8.3
```

Extracting the same archive in Python using [`Tarfile.extractall()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarFile.extractall) also extracts the `./._image.jpg` file.

I've only seen this happen with .jpg files, .txt and .xml files works as expected.

Comment: Strange! Can you a try a ls -a on the folder please? Are you deleting the tar file before creating other?

Comment: Are you running any exotic Operating System or an old version of tar? I can't reproduce this on my Ubuntu 16.04 with GNU tar 1.28.

Comment: @LucianoAndressMartini Done, no difference

Comment: @CristianMăgherușan-Stanciu Running on OSX

Comment: No difference means that the hidden .image file is there before you extract the tar file?

Comment: Could the hidden file be a thumbnail of some sort generated by Finder for images?

Comment: @LucianoAndressMartini No, the ./._image.jpg file is not in the folder before extracting the file

Comment: @CristianMăgherușan-Stanciu Could be

Comment: Someone asked a similar question here, but there are no answers https://discussions.apple.com/thread/492489?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: It turns out his was already answered here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14980/why-are-dot-underscore-files-created-and-how-can-i-avoid-them